# Rounding numbers in a table / Truncating text in table

Tags: tables, formatting

Is it possible to have automatic rounding of numbers in a table?

Say that I have this, made in the usual way with a `tabular` environment:

```
pi  | 3.14592654
e   | 2.7182818284
phi | 1.6180339887
```

**Can I control how many significant digits are shown without truncating the numbers manually myself?**

So for example, if I need four significant digits, the numbers should appear as

```
pi  | 3.1459
e   | 2.7183
phi | 1.6180
```

Bonus points for actually rounding the numbers according to the usual rules without simply truncating them.

---

I understand this is probably non-trivial, so here's a relaxed version that will also work in my circumstances (all numbers have one and the same precision and character count):

**(How) Can I control how many characters are rendered in a column of a table?**

So if I define the text in the columns as:

```
\begin{tabular} % some black magic column definition
   text & alongword\\
   text & anotherlongword\\
   text & morelongwords\\
\end{tabular}
```

I'd like to get something like:

```
text along
text anoth
text morel
```

I know there are non-TeX ways to do this, and I will probably resolve to writing a script if all else fails, but I'm curious whether there's a way to do it solely with TeX & friends.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For numbers:

There are some packages, like `siunitx` and math engine of `tikz` (especially in `pgfplotstable`), which can used to format numbers in LaTeX. `numprint` may be the simplest one, and can be easily used in tabulars.

`numprint` package privides `n` and `N` column types for numbers in tabular, and `\nprounddigits` for set the precision. An example:

```
% \usepackage{numprint} in preamble
\npdecimalsign{.}
\nprounddigits{2}
\begin{tabular}{c|n{5}{2}|}
foo & 12345 \\
bar & 12345.12345 \\
baz & 0.00012345 \\
\end{tabular}
\npnoround
```

Please read the manual for more options.

---

For common characters, @TH has showed some TeX trick. However, you can use `xstring` package or something else to do the dirty work. I don't know how to get full control in `tabular`, so here is just a incomplete solution, a mix of `xtring` and primitive TeX:

```
\halign{\StrLeft{#}{4} \cr
 abc \cr
 abcde \cr
 abcdefg \cr
}
```

Any further suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `numprint` is very nice! It has a lot other useful stuff that will certainly come in handy. Thanks!

Comment: How can I keep the header row text centered while using this package???

Comment: @Daniel: For `siunitx`, use `{header}`. For other simpler packages, use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}`

Comment: Can I specify a different amount of rounding for each column? I can't see this in the manual.

Comment: Is it possible to format a number after rounding to have a leading decimal point for values less than 1.0 i.e. I would like to see .005 instead of 0.005 ??

Comment: `numprint` makes it non-trivial to align the numbers in the columns of the table. The way I see it `siunitx` works in a less intrusive way (no preamble declarations other than the package declaration) and the number alignment just works without tweaks, as in the solution provided by @Mico below or in this [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307380/36954).

Answer (score 11):

Here's one way to do it that's a bit of a hack (which is to say that Leo Liu's answer is far better, it's just fun to try to do this yourself sometimes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fp}
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\trunc}r}
\def\trunc\ignorespaces#1\\{%
        \FPset\a{#1}
        \FPround\a\a4
        \a
        \\
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}T}
\pi  & 3.14159265358979323848\\
e    & 2.71828182845904523536\\
\phi & 1.61803399\\
x    & 37\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `T` specifier has to be at the end of the row and it must be terminated with a `\\`. You could write an analogous one that works in the middle of the row by delimiting it with `&` rather than `\\`.

The original version differed only in the definition of `\trunc`.

```
\def\trunc#1.#2#3#4#5#6\\{#1.#2#3#4#5\\}
```

Comment: @TH: It's a pity you deleted the first tricky answer (works for any characters). It's rather valuable, even only for fun. :)

Comment: @Leo: There we go, I added it back.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xstring}

\newcolumntype{N}{>{\GobbleA} r<{;;} }
\def\GobbleA\ignorespaces#1.#2;;{%
  \ignorespaces#1.\StrLeft{#2}{4}}

\newcolumntype{S}{>{\GobbleB} l }
\def\GobbleB#1#2\\{\StrLeft{#2}{4}\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} N S}
\pi  & 3.14159265358979323848 & delicious \\
e    & 2.71828182845904523536 & foo \\
\phi & 1.61803399             & extraordinarylong \\
x    & 37.11111               & { } \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't run this solution but it is particularly suitable for my problem because I see it should work using comma as separator instead of dot. However, I am getting this message everytime:

    ! Use of \@@array doesn't match its definition.
    \new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
    l.207 Lys1   &
               10.8  &    {} &  11.4267 \\
    ?

Comment: complete example, please

Comment: @jasikevicius23: have you seen `\npdecimalsign{.}` above? [The manual](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/doc/texlive-doc/latex/numprint/numprint.pdf) says: `\npdecimalsign{\ensuremath{\cdot}}\npthousandsep{,}\npproductsign{*}%
\numprint{-123456}; \numprint{3,1415927e-3.2}`
leads to “ −123,456; 3 $\cdot$ 141,592,7*10...

Answer (score 8):

Here are two solutions to the automatic rounding problem for numbers.

- The first employs the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package, with the options `round-mode=places` and `round-precision=<n>`, where `<n>` is the number of digits to be shown after the decimal marker. (The option `table-format=1.<n>` is optional but is useful if you wish to typeset the numeric column tightly.)
- The second solution uses Lua's powerful `string.format` function and thus requires LuaLaTeX. The utility LaTeX macro `\myprint` employs Lua's `string.format` function. Observe that the argument of `\myprint` is expandable;  thus, one could replace `\myprint{3.1415926536}` with `\myprint{math.pi}`. The only real requirement is that the argument of `\myprint` must evaluate to a number.

In the following table, the precision is set to `4` for the `S`-based solution and `5` for the LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-decimal-digits=false]{siunitx} % for "S" column type
\usepackage{luacode} % for \luaexec macro
% create a utility LaTeX macro:
\newcommand\myprint[1]{\luaexec{% 
   tex.sprint ( string.format ( "\%.5f" , #1 )  ) }}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\[
\begin{array}{ l 
               S[table-format=1.4,round-mode=places,round-precision=4] 
               l }
\pi        & 3.1415926536 & \myprint{3.1415926536}  \\
\mathrm{e} & 2.7182818285 & \myprint{2.7182818285}  \\
\phi       & 1.6180339887 & \myprint{1.6180339887}
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A [knitr](https://yihui.name/knitr/)-[xtable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html) approach, making a `.Rnw` file:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\renewcommand\belowcaptionskip{1ex}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,results="asis">>=
library(xtable)
x <- data.frame(Symbol=c("$\\pi$","$e$","$\\phi$","$x$"),
Value=c(3.14159265358979323848, 2.71828182845904523536, 
1.61803399, 37))
print(xtable(x,caption="Irrational numbers",align="ccr", 
digits=c(0,0,4)), 
      include.rownames=F, include.colnames=T, 
      booktabs=T, caption.placement="top",
      sanitize.text.function=function(x){x})
@
\end{document}
```

The conversion `.Rnw`→ `.tex` → `.pdf` can be done easily with Rstudio.

A more manual option is  run only the R code (lines 6-14 of the MWE) and copy & paste the LaTeX ouput in a true LaTeX document, that is in this case will be be:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.3.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Sat Sep 30 00:38:28 2017
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Irrational numbers}
\begin{tabular}{cr}
\toprule
Symbol & Value \\
\midrule
$\pi$ & 3.1416 \\
$e$ & 2.7183 \\
$\phi$ & 1.6180 \\
$x$ & 37.0000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```