# printf-style number formatting in LaTeX

Tags: formatting

Is there a way to use printf-style number formatting strings in Latex like `%.3f`, `%d`, etc?
I'm loading some data from csv files using the `datatool` package and would like to have it displayed exactly to my specifications.

Comment: Using `%` would be pretty awkward for the formatting directive in TeX, so you're not likely to see it done exactly that way

Answer (score 13):

I've no idea about `datatool`. `siunitx` provides some functions to round numbers. See manual of `siunitx`: 5.4 Parsing numbers, 5.5 Post-processing numbers

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{S[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]}
10. \\
10.1 \\
10.12 \\
10.123 \\
10.1234 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It gets:

```
10.00
10.10
10.12
10.12
10.12
```

Comment: That's not bad, but I actually need something that works anywhere in the text, not only inside tables, i.e. I'd like to do `\printf{"%.3f"}{0.3242342}` and get the output 0.324.

Comment: It does work everywhere, using `\num` command. You *should* read the manual carefully before use it, it is quite complex.

Comment: oh, I see: that's quite nice!

Comment: @oceanhug: Also see Leo's answer to this similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9132/rounding-numbers-in-a-table-truncating-text-in-table

Answer (score 9):

If you are willing to use LuaTeX

```
\directlua{tex.print(string.format("\string\%0.3f", 10.1234567))}
```

`string.format` accepts all the usual printf style arguments. The `\string\%` is needed because `%` has a special meaning in TeX.

ConTeXt provides a few helper functions so that the above can be written as

```
\ctxlua{context("\%0.3f", 10.12345)}
```

If you want, you can easily wrap the above in a macro:

```
\def\truncate#1#2%
    {\directlua{tex.print(string.format("\string\%0.#1f", #2))}}
```

or in ConText as

```
\def\truncate#1#2{\ctxlua{context("\%0.#1f", #2)}}
```

and then use

```
\truncate{3}{10.123456}
```

Comment: you need `%` not `\%` at the lua side, so `\directlua{tex.print(string.format("\@percentchar0.3f", 10.1234567))}`