# Convert dimension to integer number of mm

Tags: dimensions

I'm using \zsavepos to record the position of a box on the page and then writing the position to the box. It works fine but the functions I've got give measurements in mm to quite a few decimal places - I only need it to an integer number of millimetres...

```
\newcommand\dimtomm[1]{%
    \strip@pt\dimexpr 0.352777778\dimexpr#1\relax\relax
}
\newcommand\getPOS[3]{%
    \dimtomm{\zposx{#1}sp},\dimtomm{\zposy{#1}sp},\dimtomm{#2},\dimtomm{#3}
}
```

`\getPOS` is called with arguments of the ZPOS reference and arguments 2 and 3 are the width and height of the box. How can the `\dimtomm` function be adjusted so that it returns the number of mm as an integer and nothing else? I tried the suggestions like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126528/rounding-of-decimal-numbers-looking-for-an-elegant-way-in-latex-table) but to no avail...

Comment: are you sure you only an integer multiple of millimeters? for typography, that's not precise enough.

Comment: The conversion factor in your `\dimtomm` is wrong, as TeX's pt is `25.4/72.27 mm` and not `25.4/72 mm`. See my answer.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest no package way is to use the following macro.

```
\def\dimtomm #1{\the\numexpr \dimexpr #1\relax*635/118407168\relax }
```

But before going further I should point out that your conversion factor which is approximately `25.4/72` is wrong as TeX expresses via `\the` (which is used by the LaTeX macro `\strip@pt`) dimensions in TeX points, not Postscript points.

With the conversion factor in your question, `\dimtomm {100cm}` gives `1003.76543` and `\dimtomm {10in}` produces `254.9564`. The theoretically exact conversion factor is `25.4/72.27` which one could approximate by `0.35146`, and one would then get after this replacement `999.98828` and resp. `253.99702`.

Let's get back however to the macro to convert to a (rounded) integer multiple of millimeters.

```
\def\dimtomm #1{\the\numexpr \dimexpr #1\relax*635/118407168\relax }

\tt

1cm is \dimtomm {1cm}mm

100cm is \dimtomm {100cm}mm

1in is (approximately) \dimtomm {1in}mm

10in is \dimtomm {10in}mm

1pt is (approximately) \dimtomm {1pt}mm

100pt is (approximately) \dimtomm {100pt}mm

10000pt  is (approximately) \dimtomm {10000pt}mm

% added in post update
\the\maxdimen\ is (approximately) \dimtomm\maxdimen mm

\bye
```

If you use LaTeX, define the macro with `\newcommand` rather than `\def`, that's all. If you use plain TeX make sure you compile with `etex` or `pdftex` but not with the `tex` executable, as the e-TeX extensions must be enabled.

> [image: dimtomm]

The `\maxdimen` line produces:

> ```
> 16383.99998pt is (approximately) 5758mm
> ```

Additional note: as documented in the etex manual, a multiplication immediately followed by a division in `\numexpr` has its intermediate value computed in double precision (two words) hence no overflow arises whereas `\numexpr \maxdimen*635\relax` would generate an arithmetic overflow. Indeed `\maxdimen` is `2^30-1` `sp` units and `(2^30-1)*635` is naturally larger than the maximal allowed integer `2^31-1`.

Comment: thank you very much for this response; it seems to work great. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is using `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\dimtomm}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { round ( \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { #1 } { 1mm }, 0 ) } ~ mm
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\dimtomm{186467sp}

\end{document}
```

This prints “1 mm”, because 186467sp is exactly 1 millimeter. With `\dimtomm{10in}` you'd get ”254 mm”.

Here the length is rounded, you may want `trunc` instead of `round`.