# Round numbers in a latex table with special character header

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am trying to round numbers in the following table.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular} {c| cccc}
T(sample size) & $\theta_0$ & $\theta_1$ & $\theta_2$ & $\theta_3$ \\     \hline
200&-0.081295&-0.090014&-0.089029&0.010305\\\hline
500&-0.05266&-0.037185&-0.03383&-0.001537\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{I.I.D. contexts: bias in estimating the optimal policy parameter. Bias=$\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}_t)-\theta^*$. }
\label{iid_b}
\end{table}
```

However, if I do the following revision by replacing c with S[round-precision=2], latex compiler reports error and subscripts of theta will be lost.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular} {c| S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]}
T(sample size) & $\theta_0$ & $\theta_1$ & $\theta_2$ & $\theta_3$ \\ \hline
200&-0.081295&-0.090014&-0.089029&0.010305\\\hline
500&-0.05266&-0.037185&-0.03383&-0.001537\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{I.I.D. contexts: bias in estimating the optimal policy parameter. Bias=$\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}_t)-\theta^*$. }
\label{iid_b}
\end{table}
```

I also want to avoid changing the decimal places for each number. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|
           *{4}{S[table-auto-round,
                 table-format=-1.2]}
                }
T(sample size) & {$\theta_0$} &{$\theta_1$} & {$\theta_2$} & {$\theta_3$}\\\hline
200 &   -0.081295   &   -0.090014   &   -0.089029   &   0.010305    \\\hline
500 &   -0.05266    &   -0.037185   &   -0.03383    &  -0.001537    \\\hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption{I.I.D. contexts: bias in estimating the optimal policy parameter. Bias=$\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}_t)-\theta^*$. }
    \label{iid_b}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked very well and out of the box. Simpler than using the package `numprint` as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9139/36954). This solution only touches the preamble to declare the package import and in the column heading without upsetting the original alignment.