# Tables with columns containg the same number of decimal places

Tags: tables, amsmath, decimal-number

I need to do a Table with the following data:

```
\documentclass[t,11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[brazil,shorthands=off]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Método da bissecção}
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{14 iterações do método da bissecção para $f(x)=2-e^x$}
\label{tab:my-table}
%\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
\toprule
$k$ & $a_k$ & $p_k$ & $b_k$ & $|\log 2 - p_k|$ \\ \midrule
1.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 2.0 & 0.306853 \\
2.0 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 1.0 & 0.193147 \\
3.0 & 0.5 & 0.75 & 1.0 & 0.0568528 \\
4.0 & 0.5 & 0.625 & 0.75 & 0.0681472 \\
5.0 & 0.625 & 0.6875 & 0.75 & 0.00564718 \\
6.0 & 0.6875 & 0.71875 & 0.75 & 0.0256028 \\
7.0 & 0.6875 & 0.703125 & 0.71875 & 0.00997782 \\
8.0 & 0.6875 & 0.695312 & 0.703125 & 0.00216532 \\
9.0 & 0.6875 & 0.691406 & 0.695312 & 0.00174093 \\
10.0 & 0.691406 & 0.693359 & 0.695312 & 0.000212199 \\
11.0 & 0.691406 & 0.692383 & 0.693359 & 0.000764371 \\
12.0 & 0.692383 & 0.692871 & 0.693359 & 0.000276091 \\
13.0 & 0.692871 & 0.693115 & 0.693359 & 3.19506e-5 \\
14.0 & 0.693115 & 0.693237 & 0.693359 & 9.0194e-5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to:

1. eliminate the zeros at right in first column
2. round the columns 2, 3 and 4 with 6 decimal places and complete with zero when the number has less decimal places.
3. round the column 4 to 6 decimal places and
4. write 3.19506e-5 in decimal way.

[image]

Comment: Clarify your question. May be add a picture.

Comment: Not related: You don't have to put `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` any longer in modern LaTeX installations.

Comment: I took a liberty and move your answer in your question, where it belong!

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear, what you like to have. Your table numbers have maximal 6 decimals, not 8. Do you like to fill decimal numbers with zeros?

Anyway, I suspect that you looking for something like this:

[image]

With use of `S` columns defined in the `siunitx` package which enable customization of numbers presenting (aligning at decimal points):

```
\documentclass[t,11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[brazil,shorthands=off]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table}
    \begin{table}
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
    \small
\begin{tabular}{r*{3}{S[table-format=1.6]}}
    \hline
$k$ & $a_k$ & $p_k$ & $b_k$ \\ 
    \hline
1 & 0.0 & 0.5 & 1.0 \\
2 & 0.5 & 0.75 & 1.0 \\
3 & 0.5 & 0.625 & 0.75 \\
4 & 0.625 & 0.6875 & 0.75 \\
5 & 0.6875 & 0.71875 & 0.75 \\
6 & 0.6875 & 0.703125 & 0.71875 \\
7 & 0.6875 & 0.695312 & 0.703125 \\
8 & 0.6875 & 0.691406 & 0.695312 \\
9 & 0.691406 & 0.693359 & 0.695312 \\
10 & 0.691406 & 0.692383 & 0.693359 \\
11 & 0.692383 & 0.692871 & 0.693359 \\
12 & 0.692871 & 0.693115 & 0.693359 \\
13 & 0.693115 & 0.693237 & 0.693359 \\
14 & 0.693115 & 0.693176 & 0.693237 \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Now, after providing own (now deleted) "answer", which should bi inserted in your question, the problem is more clear. With help of further `S` column options, you can achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[t,11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[brazil,shorthands=off]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx} % <---

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Método da bissecção}
    \begin{table}
\caption{14 iterações do método da bissecção para $f(x)=2-e^x$}
\label{tab:my-table}
    \footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.0,
                  zero-decimal-to-integer]
                 *{3}{S[table-format=1.6,
                        round-integer-to-decimal,
                        round-mode=places,
                        round-precision = 6]}
                      S[table-format=1.8,
                        round-integer-to-decimal,
                        round-mode=places,
                        round-precision = 8,
                        scientific-notation = fixed, 
                        fixed-exponent = 0]}
    \toprule
$k$  & {$a_k$} & {$p_k$} & {$b_k$} & {$\abs{\log 2 - p_k}$} \\ 
    \midrule
1.0  & 0.0      & 1.0      & 2.0      & 0.306853    \\
2.0  & 0.0      & 0.5      & 1.0      & 0.193147    \\
3.0  & 0.5      & 0.75     & 1.0      & 0.0568528   \\
4.0  & 0.5      & 0.625    & 0.75     & 0.0681472   \\
5.0  & 0.625    & 0.6875   & 0.75     & 0.00564718  \\
6.0  & 0.6875   & 0.71875  & 0.75     & 0.0256028   \\
7.0  & 0.6875   & 0.703125 & 0.71875  & 0.00997782  \\
8.0  & 0.6875   & 0.695312 & 0.703125 & 0.00216532  \\
9.0  & 0.6875   & 0.691406 & 0.695312 & 0.00174093  \\
10.0 & 0.691406 & 0.693359 & 0.695312 & 0.000212199 \\
11.0 & 0.691406 & 0.692383 & 0.693359 & 0.000764371 \\
12.0 & 0.692383 & 0.692871 & 0.693359 & 0.000276091 \\
13.0 & 0.692871 & 0.693115 & 0.693359 & 3.19506e-5  \\
14.0 & 0.693115 & 0.693237 & 0.693359 & 9.0194e-5   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Note:**

- `beamer` load `graphicx` package, so you not need to (re)load it twice ...
- In LaTeX installation after April 2018 the `utf8` input encoding is default features, so no longer need to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`  in document preamble ([LATEX News](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews28.pdf)).
- Off-topic: check values in the last table columns. If they are calculated as noted in column header, than they are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *numprint* package, it allows you to round numbers in table to a certain decimal place (I think this is what you are asking for correct?).

There is another question that actually answers this, if you want to read more about it look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9132/rounding-numbers-in-a-table-truncating-text-in-table)

Comment: I would like to fill with zeros when the number has less decimal places.